# Is there a word meaning "pertaining to diary writing"?

Tags: single-word-requests, british-english

Is there a word meaning "pertaining to diary writing"? For example something like *diaretical* (obviously not a real word) or similar?

Example usage:

> The text was written in a ["diaretical"] manner.

Comment: The text was written in a *journalistic* manner. — Oh, wait...

Comment: I'm tempted to say "diuretic", but maybe not. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) has this entry for *diaristic*:

> **diaristic** *adj* (1884) of, relating to, or characteristic of a diary

A Google Books search for *diaristic* yields [several hundred matches](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22diaristic%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22diaristic%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&start=670) for the word, suggesting that the term is fairly well established. Here is the Ngram chart for *diaristic* for the period 1825–2006:

[image]

The Google Books search results also indicate that the word is older than Merriam-Webster imagines. From "[Diary Abroad.—No. 9](https://books.google.com/books?id=9CQ5AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA131&dq=%22diaristic%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=lh-8VK_tCsSwyAS5t4LoDw&ved=0CCIQ6AEwATge#v=onepage&q=%22diaristic%22&f=false)," in *Dwight's Journal of Music* (January 27, 1855) we have this unusual double instance of *Diaristic* as a noun:

> It follows moreover that articles so written take their tone from the mood of their author when they are conceived. For instance, as I read your letter the main idea of this **Diaristic** popped into my mind, and though some days have passed before I could find time to putting upon paper, I cannot keeep the cap and bells off my head. And this brings me to the second division of my discourse.
>
> Now, my dear major, just for the sake of argument, let it be granted that the unlucky **Diaristic** upon the "Prophet" was all wrong, I stand here ready to justify it to the last drop of ink.

Then, from "[Review of Current Literature](https://books.google.com/books?id=e-YWAQAAIAAJ&pg=RA1-PA150&dq=%22diaristic%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=jhy8VJC3BJSyyASIiYCoCQ&ved=0CEEQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22diaristic%22&f=false)" in *The Christian Examiner* (July 1858) we have *diaristic* as an adjective:

> Where the adventure is genuine and fresh, we need not be captious as to style. We do not blame a man for not holding th pen of Kinglake or Dr. Kane. Yet this volume is needlessly cumbersome with many **diaristic** details, with episodes rather awkwardly narrated, with many labored descriptions of sky and cloud, with a traveller's scorn (quite needlessly obtruded) of the tamer landscape of the Alps and Rhine, and with occasionally such platitudes as the following [citation omitted].

And again from John Weiss, [*Life and Correspondence of Theodore Parker*](https://books.google.com/books?id=-A86AAAAcAAJ&pg=PR6&dq=%22diaristic%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=jhy8VJC3BJSyyASIiYCoCQ&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22diaristic%22&f=false), volume 1 (1863):

> The Journal is a collection of a dozen manuscript volumes, some of them bulky ledgers, which are thickly sown with extracts, analyses of books, notifications of thinking. ... The **diaristic** matter makes a small portion of the whole contents of these volumes. I have given all of it that contributes to a knowledge of his life.

Recent usage of the term suggest that it is particularly popular in discussions of painting and film. For instance, from Marina Wallace, Martin Kemp & Joanna Bernstein, [*Seduced: Art & Sex from Antiquity to Now*](https://books.google.com/books?id=JIbqAAAAMAAJ&q=%22diaristic%22&dq=%22diaristic%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=2ya8VLejFs-cyQTY2IH4AQ&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAzgo) (2007) [combined snippets]:

> Whereas older painters may wistfully look back on their youths, Schiele was one of the few who had the technical virtuosity to express those experiences as they were happening. His watercolours and drawings, executed so rapidly and spontaneously, have a **diaristic** quality.

The term is mainstream enough to have appeared in [*The New Yorker*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Kp4eAQAAMAAJ&q=%22counterpoint+to+Stoehr%27s+sculpture%22&dq=%22counterpoint+to+Stoehr%27s+sculpture%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=aCm8VJa3HMuoyASfr4KIBA&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAA), volume 84 (2008) [combined snippets; *diaristic* is not visible in the snippet view]:

> Rather than notating current events or **diaristic** confessions, they seem to chart moods — in bursts of limpid watercolor, tight whorls of ink and ballpoint pen, patterns stamped with inked pennies. The sense of meditative accumulation in Way's work is a counterpoint to Stoehr's sculpture in the back room — titled "Tower of Babel," it's constructed of laser-cut museum board and festooned with little water tanks, cranes, scaffolding, and power lines.

Answer (score 3):

Jonathan Swift used *journalish* in 1712, but seems to have been the first and the last. He was apparently referring to the openness with which one will write when one does not expect readers:

> I never saw such a letter…so saucy, so journalish.

If nobody else has found a use for it in the last 300 years, it's probably best left alone.

Along the same lines we could consider the verb *journal*; "the text was journaled" but only if it was indeed written daily or near-daily, rather than as a comment on the style.

One way we might compare something to a diary is if it "was written in a *confessional* manner".

Another way is if it "was written in a shorthand manner".

They both fit into your example usage, and both compare to features of diary-writing, but differ greatly from each other.

Comment: "Journalish" is a fun one. :)

Comment: That's why I couldn't resist mentioning it even though it's pretty useless for actual use. Could you say more about just what features of diary-writing you are thinking off; my *confessional* and *shorthand* suggestions could be perfect or useless depending on just what you are going for.

Comment: I know that *epistolary* is about letter-writing, but the tone is the same. Diary-writing is writing a letter to oneself, so perhaps *auto-epistolary* would work. :)

Answer (score 3):

There has in fact been some scholarly interest in the diary as literary genre in the last twenty years. A quick browse in papers, theses, &c suggests that there is no adjectival form in use; writers just prepend an attributive *diary* (*diary genre*, *diary novel*).